# Twig use function multiple parameter

Tags: symfony, templates, inheritance, twig

I am looking for using function "{% use %}" with multiple parameter in twig template.

all page template

```
{% use "common.html.twig" with 
    container as containerParent,
    title as titleParent
%}
{# Some code ... #}
```

common.html.twig

```
{% block title %}{{ block(titleParent) }} - Admin{% endblock %}
{% block container %}
    {# Some code ... #}
        {{ block(containerParent) }}
    {# Some code ... #}
{% endblock %}
```

When I tried that, my block container and title are not modified.

Maybe I didn't understood the doc ? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/use.html

I just want have access to function twig {{ parent() }} in my twig file which is included by {% use ... %}

Any suggestion ?

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Comment: Have you tried `{% use "common.html.twig" with container as containerParent, title as titleParent %}` without curly braces?

Comment: Do it without the `{}` like `{% use "common.html.twig" with container as containerParent, title as titleParent %}`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but it isn't working too. But there aren't exception threw.